# php api jsonencoding result make intiger key to string [0]=>val output "0" : val

Tags: php, api, jsonencoder

```
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)]["is_decoration"]="true";                                                                                                
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)][$j]["image"]='';                                            
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)][$j]["bottom_right_x"]=$vv["bottom_right_x"];
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)][$j]['bottom_right_y']=$vv["bottom_right_y"];
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)][$j]['top_right_x']=$vv["top_right_x"];
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)][$j]['top_right_y']=$vv["top_right_y"];
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)][$j]['top_left_x']=$vv["top_left_x"];
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)][$j]['top_left_y']=$vv["top_left_y"];
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)][$j]['bottom_left_x']=$vv["bottom_left_x"];
$data['frame']["CollageDecoration"]["ClgD".$this->actionApiNumToWord($i+1)][$j]['bottom_left_y']=$vv["bottom_left_y"];

echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

output:

```
"ClgDFour": {   // this 0 is integer but it give "0" like string index
                "0": {
                    "image": "",
                    "bottom_right_x": "0.6973036342321218",
                    "bottom_right_y": "0.5270833333333333",
                    "top_right_x": "0.6973036342321218",
                    "top_right_y": "0.32708333333333334",
                    "top_left_x": "0.5885111371629543",
                    "top_left_y": "0.32708333333333334",
                    "bottom_left_x": "0.5885111371629543",
                    "bottom_left_y": "0.5270833333333333"
                },
                "is_decoration": "true"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON keys must be strings. That is why it is a string in the output.

Read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) to learn more about JSON objects.